# Which preposition: "on", "at" or "in"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on-at

Soon I'll meet a native speaker and I'd like to know what expression is correct when I want to introduce an anecdote:

> 1. **at** one occasion
> 2. **in** one occasion
> 3. **on** one occasion

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Valeria - I'm going to re-open this because searching for an answer about the right preposition to use in a context can be tricky and I think that some folks aren't thinking about some of the other definitions of occasion that could send you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 3):

According to Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary:

1  [countable] a particular time when something happens on this/that occasion

I've met him on several occasions.

They have been seen together on two separate occasions.

On one occasion, she called me in the middle of the night.

Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th edition © Oxford University Press, 2015

Comment: "Occasion" is also used to refer to a special event or ceremony.  So "at one occasion" could refer to something happening at a particular special event.